# Replacing "-+" in a string with "-" using the replaceAll() method does not do anything, yet all other replaceAll() methods do?

Tags: java, math, methods, replaceall

I'm making a program in java which will add or subtract any amount of numbers regardless of how the expression is formatted by the user. The program is as follows:

```
package addemup;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class AddEmUp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter something like 8 + 33 + 1,345 +137 : ");
        String s = kb.nextLine();

        s = s.replaceAll(",", "");
        s = s.replaceAll(" ", "");
        s = s.replaceAll("--", "+");
        s = s.replaceAll("-+", "-");
        s = s.replaceAll("-", "+-");
        s = s.replaceAll("\\++", "+");

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(s);
        sc.useDelimiter("\\s*\\+\\s*");

        // System.out.println(s);
        int runningTotal = 0;
        while (sc.hasNextInt()) {
            runningTotal = runningTotal + sc.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println(runningTotal);
    }


}
```

First, the program prompts the user to input an expression consisting of integers, adding, and subtracting operations. Then, the program alters the string that is inputted as to format it into something that can be processed. It is then processed using a Scanner object and the result is printed.

The problem lies with the replacing of an operation. When "-+" is replaced with "-", it does not replace it in the string as I saw in the debug menu. Logically, this should not be an issue as subtracting a positive number is the same as adding a negative number, where the program later replaces the "-" with a "+-". All of the other replaces work fine. It's just in that one replace with "-+" that does not seem to want to work.

So how come only this replaceAll method does not want to work when all the others work just fine?

The program completes 10 - 10 just fine, resulting in 0. However, I would like to account for the case that the user does something like 10 - +10, which is really the same thing. Instead, that results in 10 instead of 0.

I went through the debug menu and found that the replaceAll "-+" method does not seem to do anything. This is really strange as all the other replaceAll methods work just fine.

Comment: Forgot to escape the `+` on that line. You escaped it on the other lines, just not that one.

Comment: Use `replace`, not `replaceAll` (`replace` replaces _all_, `replaceAll` replaces all _and_ interprets the needle as regular expression which you don't want - see linked question's answer for more detail).